# Which Javascript version(s) does IE8 supports?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

According to Wikipedia, IE8 only supports Javascript 1.5. So they are saying IE8 completely ignores Javascript versions 1.6, 1.7, 1.8 and 1.9.

Should I trust? Is it true?

Comment: You should go update the Wikipedia article with what you've learned here.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Well, actually the IE implementation is called [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28VS.85%29.aspx), JavaScript(TM) is the implementation of Mozilla.

JScript and JavaScript are two [ECMAScript](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php)-based dialects.

JavaScript 1.5 conforms with the [ECMAScript 3rd Edition Standard](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/), the subsequent versions, JS 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8 introduce language features that are out of that standard edition, often called *Mozilla Extensions*.

That's why JScript doesn't have any of these features, because they are not part of the ECMA Standard.

Comment: ECMAscript 5 was published in December 2009 (several months before this answer), incorporating many of these new features into the standard.

Comment: Does IE8 support ECMAscript 5 then?

Comment: @BenNelson Broadly speaking, NO. Source: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#ie8

Answer (score 18):

This test taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/16907f1c-6f59-4c68-b763-d6e3028903bd) returns `1.3` in my Internet Explorer 8 64-bit.

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.3">
jsver = "1.3";
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.4">
jsver = "1.4";
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.5">
jsver = "1.5";
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.6">
jsver = "1.6";
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.7">
jsver = "1.7";
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript1.8">
jsver = "1.8";
</SCRIPT>

<BODY>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
document.write("<B>Your browser supports JavaScript version " + jsver + ".</B>")
</SCRIPT>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15):

IE doesn't support JavaScript at all. “JavaScript” specifically refers to Mozilla's implementation of the ECMAScript standard. This standard was originally derived from Netscape/Mozilla's work on the language, but they have since diverged. IE's implementation of ECMAScript is called “JScript”, and it does not support many of the extensions Mozilla have made.

The version of ECMAScript IE aims for is the Third Edition standard, which is also version JavaScript 1.5 was aimed at, which is why they're considered similar. The JavaScript engines of Opera, Safari and Chrome all target this same version; whilst all the implementations have bugs that mean they don't quite exactly meet the spec, in general ECMAScript Third Edition is a solid baseline for what works today.

The next version of ECMAScript is the Fifth Edition, which was standardised recently. All browsers are picking up features from this spec and it is hoped it will become as widely-supported in the future. It does not align to any particular “JavaScript” version; it notably picks up some useful `String` and `Array` methods that were previously in JavaScript 1.5, but you won't find most of Mozilla's syntactical extensions to JS in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is true (at least as far as which language features are supported). You can easily check this using some Javascript 1.6 code:

```
alert([1,2,3].indexOf(2));
```

IE 8 throws an error.

Note that IE 8 might support some of the features added in later versions of Javascript. IE contains a lot of stuff outside the standards, so it's likely that some of it happens to be the same as the later additions.