# With JavaScript is it possible to detect the current version of JavaScript supported in the browser?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [To tell Javascript version of your browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242109/to-tell-javascript-version-of-your-browser)

With JavaScript is it possible to detect the current version of JavaScript supported in the browser?

I'm looking for something similar to `navigator.userAgent` but for the JavaScript version.

EDIT: I'm not asking that to perform feature detection. I'm digging more into JavaScript, and use my browsers' javascript consoles. I would like to know for each of my browsers if they support ECMAScript Edition 5 for instance.

Comment: use jquery?? that i think makes sure that it is supported

Comment: Lol, no amount jQuery will help you much. Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't reliable ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
<script language="Javascript">var jsversion = 1.0;</script>
<script language="Javascript1.1"> jsversion = 1.1;</script>
<script language="Javascript1.2"> jsversion = 1.2;</script>
<script type=text/javascript>
    console.log("Your javascript version is " + jsversion );
</script>
```

Almost the same as Neal [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242109/to-tell-javascript-version-of-your-browser)...

Comment: BEAT ME! hahaha, same post. good stuff +1